# Swipe Details View

Tags: android

I have ListView with items. I'm using XML to parse data. In that moment I parse data for one item in DetailsView. When I clicked on item, how to make DetailsView for items with SwipeViews beetween items? How to implement with ViewPager? I try to develop some examples, but didn't work. I would be grateful if someone help me.

Comment: Do you want to swipe between ListView items when you clicked one of the items?

Comment: When I click on ListView item, I go to another activity. In that activity I want to display details with SwipeViews, swipe between details.

Comment: Oh, the details for clicked ListView item. OK i will post the code in few minutes.

Comment: With few minutes i mean like 30 minutes, I'm editing the code sorry, btw, are you able to get details?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I get the details like this.
TextView titleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
  titleText.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("title"));
Yes, I'm able to get the details.

Comment: I mean did you parse your XML data to ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first create a `Fragment` for your detail. This is for a single detail. The detail that you'll swipe. So apply your layout to this.

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Detail extends Fragment {


     private final String detail;


        public DetailView(String detail) {
            this.detail = detail;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailText);
        textView.setText(detail);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Now create your `Activity`. This is the `Activity` that you will go when you clicked. Now the code adds a `Fragment` for every detail.

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

 public static ViewPager mPager;
 private MyAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager1);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    //The count of details. This will return 5 swipeable views.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

             return new Detail("I'm a detail!");

              }
}


}
```

This will create 5 details with text "I'm a detail!". Now, i assume you are using `ArrayList` that storing details. Then you can get the details like this:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(fm);
        data = d;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     map = data.get(position);
     Log.d("", data.get(position).toString());

             return new Detail(map.get('KeyForYourDetail'));


              }
}
```

Also on your `MainActivity` change

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

to this

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), yourArrayList);
```

**EDIT**

Let's start from the beginning. First, you have your `MainActivity` which contains a `ListView`.  In the `ListView`, you are calling items from `ArrayList`. When you click a item, you get the detail about it from (?). Now my above code can't do that. You have to do that your own first. After you get the detail, just replace the `title` part below. To summarize, the code i post should work if you can get the "detail", if you don't know how to get detail, then you should create another question.

```
return new Detail(title);
```

**EDIT 2**

OK, here is the other part. Below code is for FragmentActivity.

First, we need to declare our adapter and `ViewPager`.

```
public static ViewPager mPager;
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> detailList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

MyAdapter is the adapter that puts the details into `ViewPager`. To hold details, we also need an `ArrayList` as i declared above. Now, you said you don't have problem with parsing. So I'm skipping that part. While you're parsing, I assume you are using `NodeList`(i took that part from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/))

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
```

// looping through all item nodes 
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME); // name child value
    String cost = parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST); // cost child value
    String description = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC); // description child value
}

Inside of your for loop, create a `HashMap` like this

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Remember while we were creating our `ArrayList`? It's object was `HashMap`. Now we are going to fill our data to map, then add map to ArrayList. (Again, this goes inside of for loop)

```
 map.put(TAG_DETAIL, detail);
 detailList.add(map);
```

Now this part is over, only thing left is setting the adapter.

```
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), detailList);
 mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And we are done! Let me explain what's going to happen next. Do you remember our adapter?

```
 public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(fm);
        data = d;
    }
```

Here as you see, it takes a `FragmentManger` and an `ArrayList` with `Hashmap` inside of it. we set those with `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `detailList`. Adapter takes the detailList with details inside of it, then creates `Fragments` with it. I hope it was clear enough. If wasn't, ask again.

Comment: That's great! I'm using ArrayList. Thank you. If I have any problems, I will write to you.

Comment: AnketSoruDetay what is this class?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change its the Detail Fragment.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I'm using ArrayAdapter to transfer data.
onItemClick method:
String title = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getTitle();
in.putExtra("pos", pos);
in.putExtra("title", title);
startActivity(in);

Comment: I really don't have time right now, please post your current code if you can, i will look up when i found time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of MyAdapter.java:

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;


public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int textViewResourceId, List<NewsFeed> sites) {
    super(ctx, textViewResourceId, sites);

    //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .build();
}


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 * 
 * This method is responsible for creating row views out of a StackSite object that can be put
 * into our ListView
 */
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
    Log.i("Feed", "getView pos = " + pos);
```

//      if(null == row){
//          //No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
//          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//          row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
//      }

```
    if (pos != 0){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    else
    {
        //No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_first_item, null);
    }


    //Get our View References
    final ImageView iconImg = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconImg);
    TextView titleTxt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
    final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    //Initially we want the progress indicator visible, and the image invisible
    indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iconImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Setup a listener we can use to swtich from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
    ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            iconImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
    imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(pos).getImgUrl(), iconImg,options, listener);

    //Set the relavent text in our TextViews
    titleTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());

    return row;


}
```

}

Comment: So this is for your current ListView, right? If so, how are you getting the details?

Comment: Yes, this is for my ListView. I get the details like this:
String title = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getTitle();
     
Intent in= new Intent(FeedActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
in.putExtra("pos", pos);
in.putExtra("title", title); 
startActivity(in);

Comment: titleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
titleText.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("title"));

Comment: If your detail is getIntent().getExtras().getString("title"));  , then put it on `return new Detail();` . I'm sorry i really can't understand your code you have to be more specific, Also, you shouldn't answer your own question unless its the answer. I suggest you to edit your question (delete this one), and explain the classes. What is FeedActivity, what is DetailsActivity? Where do you get details from?

Comment: FeedActivity.java is an Activity, here is the ListView. DetailsActivity.java is a FragmentActivity with the details.

Comment: FragmentActivity just contains ViewPager, your adapter is also in FragmentActivity. Then on Adapter's getView method, you create the Fragments from Detail Fragment with details.

Comment: Ok, Of course, that's, but I don't understand which adapter to use, FragmentPagerAdapter or ArrayAdapter. I think FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Can you give me example with parsing data.

Comment: You are right, FragmentPagerAdapter, i would but it will take time i have a homework i have to do for tomorrow, if you can wait i will post it, meanwhile you can search yourself. There are plenty good tutorials out there, You can try parsing XML, androidhive has a good tutorial about it as i can remember.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will wait. Ok, post some tutorials. I haven't problem with parsing of XML. I have problem with that I haven't idea how to put the XML in the FragmentPagerAdapter and display it.

Comment: Oh, that's the easy part if you can parse the data, i will post the code when i have time, probably tonight.